# Tslint errors shown in Bitbucket but not in local development environment

Tags: bitbucket, tslint

So, I'm wondering why I'm getting TSLint errors in Bitbucket. When I run the TSLint command during the development, it didn't show the error.

Errors:

> ERROR: src/XXXController.ts[134, 13]: The key 'aXXX' is not sorted
>   alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/XXXController.ts[153, 21]: The key 'dXXX' is
>   not sorted alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/adaptors/XXXAdaptor.ts[97, 21]:
>   The key 'aXXX' is not sorted alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/adaptors/XXXAdaptor.ts[108, 25]: The key 'pXXX' is not sorted
>   alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/adaptors/YYYAdaptor.ts[107, 21]: The key
>   'aXXX' is not sorted alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/adaptors/YYYAdaptor.ts[118, 25]: The key 'pXXX' is not sorted
>   alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/clients/YYYClient.ts[164, 13]: The key
>   'cXXX' is not sorted alphabetically 
>   ERROR:src/clients/YYYClient.ts[168, 17]: The key 'pXXX' is not sorted
>   alphabetically

--Additional Information--

IDE: Visual Studio Code

TSLint command: `node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint *.ts 'src/**/*.ts'`

Content of `tslint.json`:

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "ordered-imports": false,
        "no-console": false
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Content of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
     "lib": ["es6", "dom", "esnext" ],
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: there could be a different tsconfig.json at the bitbucket?

Comment: @AshwinKJoseph shouldn't it read the same tsconfig found in my project directory?

Comment: there was a time when I had a similar error, my development setup was reading from the global tsconfig I am sorry I dont remember how I fixed it

Comment: Ok. I'll checked if it's reading a different tsconfig.

Comment: I tried to specify the tsconfig to use but output is still the same.

Command: `node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint -c tslint.json *.ts 'src/**/*.ts'`

Comment: ooops. wrong. I used tslint.json. Sorry